# Frameset Doctype

Tags: html, doctype, frameset

If we use frameset doctype, can we use normal html tags outside of the frameset tag within that page?

Below is the code;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

    <html:html locale="true">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        </head>

    <frameset cols="*" rows="40,*">
            <frame src="#" />
            <frame src="#"/>
            <noframes>
                <body>
                Please enable frames to view.
                </body>
            </noframes>
        </frameset>

    <a href="#">Is this Normal Anchor Tag allowed for frameset doctype and if yes, is this the correct position ?</a>

    </html:html>
```

Comment: Did you read [the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd)? It comes with an example and describes how frameset.dtd differs from the regular DTD.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not add another frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't put any content outside the frameset, and that has nothing to do with the doctype.

You can only put content inside the body tag, and a frameset page has no body tag (except inside the `noframes` tag).

Comment: So that's exactly my question...Since there is no body tag for the frameset page, where will the other HTML code go..e.g. a simple link..

Comment: @hmthr: There is no other code in a frameset page. It can only contain frames, nothing else. If you want both frames and content in the same page, you should use the `iframe` tag instead.

Comment: So if I have a frameset with 2 frames (as in my original post), can I convert it easily into iframe? Also I guess iframe also will have an src attribute...So where will the additional HTML code go ? Also what about the doctype for iframe?

Comment: @hmthr: Iframes works completely different from framesets, so there is no easy conversion. You put an iframe tag within a regular page, so you can have your other content around it however you like. You might need a transitional doctype to make a valid page with an iframe, depending on which version of HTML you use, but you can easily test this by validating the page.

Comment: Ok..I get the point..So I can have the height for an iframe..just like we have used <frameset cols="*" rows="40,*">  ?

Comment: Also if I use <frameset onload="javascript:LoadPage()">...it is giving an error "Can't find variable: LoadPage"....Not sure why it is giving an error..I have defined LoadPage()

Comment: @hmthr: You don't set the size of an iframe the same way as a frame, you set it's size like a regular HTML element. To use an event in the frameset, you would have to define the function in the frameset page, not in the page that you load in the frame.

Comment: Ok..I got the sizing thing..But when you say  "define the function in the frameset page, not in the page that you load in the frame"..that sounds the same page to me. Could you please clarify on that..

Comment: @hmthr: You need to have the script in the same page as you have the `frameset` tag.